# What do I do about re-seating this old flange?

Tags: toilet, flange

Not a big DIY'er historically, getting into it..anyways, figured replacing this toilet would be straightforward but my house is from the 1950's...anyways, removed the toilet to find the following...in images.

https://www.icloud.com/sharedalbum/#B0PG6XBubJOKSDs

Also, there's dirt and roots in there? That's probably a terrible sign. Anywho, there's one solid thread in there to reattach the flange? What about the other 3?

This thing isn't even a pipe it seems like? Seems like it was made by hand?

Thanks for all of the help!

Comment: Slab on grade or crawlspace?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix this toilet flange?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/177598/how-do-i-fix-this-toilet-flange) - you need repair flange like that; just the ring.

Comment: I believe this is slab on grade..1 story house master bedroom in Texas

Comment: Hi! Please consider [registering](/help/why-register) one of your accounts then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: @Mazura I don't think so. My biggest concern is how do I securely mount the flange to the floor? I only have one place it seems to screw it in and I am not sure what sort of anchors used to be there or how to reseat them. That article did give me the idea of using excess wax to seal some of the crcks.

Comment: My other concern is that the "pipe" if you will is totally irregular. There would be no way I could get one of those PVC flanges in there with the expanding gasket because it is just not straight by any means. This thing is like a hardened clay hole in the ground.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that's a pretty advanced state of decay. I'll guess that the pipe is cast iron and hope the stuff you see that looks like dirt is finely crumbling bits of rusted pipe. It looks like the end of the pipe is broken away such that it would be hard to make a reliable gasket seal between the toilet and the pipe.

It's worth noting that it's always important for a toilet to be securely attached to the flange. Any amount of rocking will eventually cause a wax ring gasket to fail. If you do attempt to make this work with some kind of gaskets, having the toilet secured to the floor would be especially critical.

Since you're kind of warming up the DIY muscles... how do you feel about replacing that flooring? I'd be thinking real hard about breaking out a hole in the concrete floor. It might have to be 1-2 feet long on each side -- large enough to be able to remove the gravel or dirt beneath, cut off the failing portion of the pipe, and install new pipe, elbow, and closet flange. Finish it off with a bit of new concrete mixed in a bucket or wheelbarrow and then new flooring.

Comment: I'd love to tell you it's just decayed pipe but I literally found roots...

Comment: As far as how I feel about all of that..this literally started off as just trying to use a toilet tank repair kit...couldn't get the main gasket to seal on the old bowl well and figured I would just get a new toilet. Left bolt came off from the flange just fine, right bolt did not, well there's why...

Are you talking about digging all the way down to the elbow where the pipe goes horizontal? Or just digging deep enough to cut off a piece of the vertical pipe?

Comment: I'd go in expecting to entirely replace the elbow, and probably a few inches of horizontal pipe too. The reason is that a rubber coupler is most of 4 inches long and needs a few inches of straight pipe to clamp to. There's probably not enough good pipe remaining on top of the elbow nor enough vertical space available to slip a coupling in. Thus the whole elbow may have to go.

Comment: Well, that escalated quickly, +1. "This thing is like a hardened clay hole in the ground." @Ken - I suspect (hope) it's plumber's putty. Step one before ripping it all out is seeing if you can clean that up a bit with a chisel. *Then* we'll see how far down the rabbit hole this can of worms goes.

Comment: Once upon a time I wanted to paint a bathroom and resolved to move the toilet aside so I could access the drywall behind it. Upon moving the toilet I found that the flange was two inches too close to the wall and somebody had chipped out the front edge of the flange, elbow, and concrete to "make it work." I estimate it had been that way for 20 years. When I broke out the concrete to make repairs I discovered a cavern that took one and a half wheelbarrows of soil (about 10 cu ft) to fill!